# Simple math Java program, if statements not working

Tags: java, math, if-statement

I am having trouble getting this program to work properly, it takes 2 numbers then does the type of math you tell it to do. I wrote this just to refresh my memory having not worked with java for a few months. Here is the code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class math {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner one = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner two = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
        int n1 = one.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter a second number: ");
        int n2 = one.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Add, subtract, multiply, or divide? ");
        String f = two.nextLine();
        System.out.println(f);
        if (f=="add"){
            System.out.println(n1 + n2);
        }else if (f=="subtract") {
            if (n1>n2){
                System.out.println(n1 - n2);
            }else{
                System.out.println(n2 - n1);
            }
        }else if (f=="multiply"){
            System.out.println(n1 * n2);
        }else if (f=="divide"){
            if (n1>n2){
                System.out.println(n1 / n2);
            }else{
                System.out.println(n2 / n1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Edit: Thank you all, it works with f.equals()

Comment: [String.equals(String)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html)

Comment: String.equals() compares content. == compares locations. For comparing string literals and interned strings, == will work. In all other cases, .equals() is the only option. Basically, .equals()

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your String comparisons need to be changed to use `String.equals()` instead of `==`:

```
if (f=="add"){
```

To

```
if ("add".equals(f)){
```

and

```
    }else if (f=="subtract") {
```

to

```
    }else if ("subtract".equals(f)) {
```

etc.

Comment: That worked, thank you. Is there a similar way to test if there is a single character or certain string of text inside of variable f? Such as this: if (f contains the string "enter string here") {do this}

Comment: f.contains(CharSequence c)  :) you can use a string in the place of a charsequence

Answer (score 3):

```
if (f=="add")
```

compares references. You need to

```
if(f.equals("add"))
```

because java has many objects and mainly == is used for reference comparing unless you are not doing it for primitives.

If you want to check if it has a string inside,

```
if(f.contains("asdas"))
```

Answer (score 3):

You're comparing strings with `==`, use `f.equals("add")` instead (same with other comparisons). Generally, `==` should only be used on primitive data types as opposed to objects (like `String`s).

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class math {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a number: ");
        int n1 = in.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Enter a second number: ");
        int n2 = in.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Add, subtract, multiply, or divide? ");
        String f = in.nextLine();
        System.out.println(f);
        if (f.equals("add")) {
            System.out.println(n1 + n2);
        } else if (f.equals("subtract")) {
            if (n1 > n2){
                System.out.println(n1 - n2);
            } else {
                System.out.println(n2 - n1);
            }
        } else if (f.equals("multiply")) {
            System.out.println(n1 * n2);
        } else if (f.equals("divide")) {
            if (n1>n2) {
                System.out.println(n1 / n2);
            } else {
                System.out.println(n2 / n1);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Also, there's no need to use two `Scanner` instances, one will suffice. Just as a side note, strings have an `equalsIgnoreCase` method as well which will test for equality but ignore the cases of the characters.

Answer (score 0):

While

```
f.equals("add");
```

will work, if I enter Add, it won't work. To fix this you can replace   f.equals("word") with

```
f.equalsIgnoreCase("add");
```

which allows any case, AdD will work, ADD will work, aDD will work, etc.

Hope this helps!